# Как подключить bootstrap на страницу в nodejs?

Tags: node.js, html5, bootstrap, npm

Установил nodejs, expressjs.
Не получается подключить локальный bootstrap к html файлу.
Не работает именно при localhost:3000. Если запустить отдельный index.html, то все локальные пути работают.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">  


    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>    
      </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "bootstrap-protipe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.6"
  }
}
```

Сервер запускается app.js

```
        var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
                res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html');
        })

    app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    });
```

Comment: а какой-нибудь другой локальный `css` получается подключить? П.С. - никогда ничего не ложите в папку `node_modules`

Comment: Так модули по умолчанию устанавливаются в node_modules. Собственно npm i --save bootstrap.

Comment: лучше бы Вы на вопрос ответили, который Вам задали

Comment: Прошу прощения. Другой файл подключить также не получается. в консоле выдает ошибку  - Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Чтобы раздавать файлы с локального сервера, не мешало бы использовать express.static('public'). public - это название директории на твоём сервере, в которой ты хотел бы положить некоторые статические файлы для раздачи. Т.е. в том месте, где лежит твой index.js ты создаёшь папку public, кидаешь в неё bootstrap.min.js. После этого добавляешь в index.js такую строку: app.use(express.static('public')) и всё. Далее ты можешь в index.html прописать в атрибуте src тега script src="bootstrap.min.js" и файл с bootstrap должен подтянуться

Comment: Спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создал в главной директории каталог public. Перенес в него index.html, и все файлы получилось примерно следующее.

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">        
  </head>
  <body>
      <script src="vue.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();        
    app.use(express.static('public'))
    app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

app.js:

```
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]